# How to check if a particular CSS value exists

Tags: jquery, css

Why won't this work?

Browser = Safari

```
<p style="color:blue;">foo</p>

if ($("p").css(("color") === "blue")) {
        alert(1);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all about syntax and brackets:

```
if ($("p").css("color") === "blue") {
        alert(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel very dumb!

Answer (score 4):

Initially, the bracket placement is wrong. You should be *getting* the value of the CSS property "color" with `.css("color")` and testing for equality with your value like so:

```
if ($('p').css('color') === 'blue') {
    alert('color is blue');
}
```

However, some browsers will return the `rgb` value instead which will not match your "blue", for example Chrome and Firefox return `rgb(0, 0, 255)` for `$('p').css('color')`, so you might want to test against the rgb (or even hex - '#0000ff') value as well. All the values are logically but not textually the same.

```
var color = $('p').css('color')
if (color === 'blue' || color === 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' || color === '#0000ff') {
    alert('color is blue');
}
```

Taking it even further, the *if condition* should probably take into account the case of the color. 'BLUE' or '#0000FF' are also valid.

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be : `if ($("p").css("color") === "blue"){ alert(1); }`

Answer (score 0):

At least in Firefox and Chrome

```
$("p").css("color")
```

returns rgb(0,0,255) so your condition will not be true anyway. So maybe such workaround:

```
if ($("p").attr("style").contains('color:blue;')) {
    alert(1);
}
```